# How to generate a N stack of random tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

A pythonic way would be just to write:

```py
[tf.random.uniform([3,3]) for i in range(5)]
```

In my case `tf.random.uniform([3,3])` would be changed to `myFunction()` that returns random tensors of constant shape.

I could just do:

```
myStack = tf.stack([myFunction() for i in range(5)])
```

But this is has a terrible performance.

What would be an elegant tensorflow way of having a stack of these `5 x [3,3]` tensors? (Returning value should be a collection of `[3,3]` tensors. Obviously it can't be a python list due to poor performance)

I could make this to work using `tf.tile`, `tf.while_loop`, but that feels like too much of hacking.
Is there a clean way?

Comment: Why not do `tf.random.uniform([5,3,3])`?

Comment: `tf.tile` would repeat the same tensor several times, is that what you want? Or you want several _different_ random tensors? If you cannot get `myFunction` to directly generate a `(5, 3, 3)` tensor, then the options that you mention (a Python loop, `tf.while_loop` and `tf.tile`) are all reasonable, not sure what feels like "hacking" about them. Maybe giving a bit more context (e.g. what is `myFunction`, why is the performance so terrible, etc.) or what kind of syntax were you expecting to find could help.

Comment: `myFunction()` can't generate (5,3,3) directly, it only can do (3,3) and the result is random. The problem I'm facing the that TensorFlow performs poor when I do such simple Python list comprehension